# MVC3 Localized display name attribute by property name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, data-annotations

I have recently learned how to create a localized display names for my model's properties using the following article: [Simplified localization for DataAnnotations](http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/simplified-localization-for-dataannotations/#.UZ3me6JSjqs)

And I am now trying to push it a bit further by removing the parameters from the constructor.
Meaning instead of having this

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("User_Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("User_FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("User_LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have this

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now the question is how do I let this class:

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    private PropertyInfo _nameProperty;
    private Type _resourceType;

    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string className, string propertyName)
        : base(className + (propertyName == null ? "_Class" : ("_" + propertyName)))
    {

    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return LanguageService.Instance.Translate(base.DisplayName) ?? "**" + base.DisplayName + "**";
        }
    }
}
```

Know my property's name without having to specify it in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me.

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        [Display(Name = "EmailID", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to your case, but I'm using Model Meta data extensions for localizing my models. It keeps the model cleaner. Have you tried these?

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx