# Two labels for two elements with the same id, but different forms. Why doesn't works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/TTKeW/) has the perfect scenario that I'm facing.

In some cases I have two elements with the same `id` in my application. All jQuery and JavaScripts functions works ok because I can distinguish them by the `form` element.

But my `label`s get messed with that even knowing their *owner form*(`.form` attribute). I can figure out why it behaves that way. It's a little senseless, I think.

I'm wondering if this can be achieved or if it is just impossible.

**UPDATE**

Just an explanation of *why* some `id`s repeats is that my application run over ASP.Net Mvc so the elements are generated by the MVC Helpers like e.g. `EditorFor`. So it gives me the `id`, I didn't *chose* they.

Comment: The root of your problem is the re-use of an "id" value. They have to be unique on the page or else things won't work properly.

Comment: @Pointy is that way because I'm using Asp.Net Mvc `HTML.EditorFor` helper to generate the `input`s. I don't chose the `id`, you know?

Comment: Than your tool is broken.

Comment: `id should be unique`

Comment: ID must be unique [Read This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown If you're using `Html.EditorFor` then it means you're using it twice for the same property correct?

Comment: @jumpingcode Not exactly. Think on this: I have a form then over it can have a jQuery dialog loading anohter form. The first form have a `Code` field for, e.g. a employee and the dialog form have a `Code` field for a company. They're different but with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it seems as if though you are using two `Models` with the same property on. Taking your example `Code` on both an `Employee` and `Company`. When your HTML is being rendered, it is setting the property name as the `ID` on each element representing that property so `Employee.Code` and `Company.Code` have been assigned the same ID.

To remedy this, instead of:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Code)
```

Use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Code, new { id = "Employee_Code" })
```

Thus your IDs will be unique and will solve the problems you are having.

Comment: I was afraid of that because I have about mmm.. 350 views. I were looking for a solution that I have not to change those calls.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown That is..going to be painful

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Try having a look at this, seems like you can specify the `ID` on the model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711579/mvc3-localized-display-name-attribute-by-property-name

Comment: That's a nice tip, surely I'll take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

An ID should be unique. Use classes or a unique IDs.

Comment: Can a label work with classes? Never see that, please tell if it can.

Comment: Yes you can do `<label class="you-class" ...>`  Just make sure that your jQuery code is not using the duplicated IDs.  Also, you might want to check why your MVC tool is doing that. There's probably something wrong from the way you are using or with Microsoft. (or both)